# Outdated & latest dependencies conflict in spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have a problem creating a spring-boot microservice. Let's say I have two projects,

- Project A refers to a functional spring-boot microservice.
- Project B refers to a java client that make use of a large amount of libraries in order to perform high level transactions to a core System.

Now, both of them work great, however, when I try to merge both projects in order to "Expose the core system through microservices" I get a lot of exceptions, such as:

- java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.
- Outdated dependencies because Project A make use of project B libs, the opposite, and so on...

Perhaps the approach to "create" the core system client within the microservice endpoint methods and merging the large amount of libraries is not the most friendly.

What about **isolating both project in order to keep their own libraries but allow project A (microservice) to make use of some project B methods to access the core system.** Do you know how to achieve this? any recommendations?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `Project A refers to a functional spring-boot microservice.`...

Comment: Hi, It refers to a spring-boot archeotype that basically implements a rest.

Comment: if you are referencing to an archetype then you can't use it cause an archetype is a kind of template for a project not a real project which you can use? Maybe I misunderstand a thing here...Do you have an example project?